# Integrating a multivariate normal probability density function over circular region

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals, normal-distribution

Suppose the position of one point fulfills the bivariate normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\alpha, \sigma^2 I_2)$, where $\alpha = (0,0)$, $\sigma^2$ is a scalar and $I_2$ is the identity matrix of order $2\times 2$.

Now I want to compute $K$, representing the probability that this point falls into the circle $(x-r_0)^2 + y^2 = r_0^2$, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
  K = \iint_S f(x,y)\, \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
  S = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: (x - r_0)^2 + y^2 \leq r_0^2\}
\end{equation}

After the polar conversion,
\begin{equation}
  K = \int_0^{r_0}\int_0^{2\pi} f(r,\theta)r \,\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta,
\end{equation}
where
$f(r,\theta) = (2\pi)^{-1} \sigma^{-2}\mathrm{exp}\left\{ 
-\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 (r_0^2+r^2 + 2r_0r\cos\theta)\right\}$.

How about the result of this integral?

Comment: The two  dimensional Lebesgue measure of $S$ is $0$, so the value of $\iint_S f(x,y)\, \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y$ is also  $0$.

Comment: Do you mean the *circle* (with no interior) or the *disc* (with an interior)?

Comment: Sorry, the region should be modified to $S = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: (x-r_0)^2 + y^2 \leq r_0^2\}$